# How can we show and error symbol (like '!') in case of an error in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using ReactJS + MaterialUI components. I want to highlight to the user and show '!' mark when there is an error in a tab. I am looking to put an error mark on the tab name so that the user can click to see more.

Is there any way to show this?

Comment: By tab do you mean input?

Comment: 'Tab' is a component in materialUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-ioxsf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Add `import ErrorIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Error"` to import error icon.

```
{showOrNotToShow && (
            <div
              style={{ marginTop: "15px", cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => {
                alert("something");
              }}
            >
              <ErrorIcon />
            </div>
          )}
```

Conditional render if error then show error icon.